# Is there any way to configure Redis to be case insensitive with regards to Keys?

Tags: redis

So for example:

```
Foo : Bar
```

Could also be looked up as FOO, foo, fOO etc?

Comment: And what has this to do with Python?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No. You should lowercase/uppercase all your keys if you want that.

Answer (score 6):

redis keys is case sensitive,my solution is that:
key-->Foo:Bar
keyword-->f

keys("[fF]*")
or
keyword-->foo

keys("[fF][oO][oO]*")
you have to convert normal string to this format '[Ff][Oo]';

i write a method for this:

```
public static String toIgnoreCasePattern(String str){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    char []chars = str.toCharArray();
    char upperCaseC;
    for(char c : chars){
        boolean isLowerCase = Character.isLowerCase(c);
        upperCaseC = isLowerCase ? Character.toUpperCase(c) : c;
        sb.append("[").append(c).append(upperCaseC).append("]");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

I hope this answer can help you.

Answer (score 2):

In C#

```
public static String toIgnoreCasePattern(String str)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    char[] chars = str.ToCharArray();
    char upperCaseC;
    foreach (var c in chars)
    {
        bool isLowerCase = char.IsLower(c);
        upperCaseC = isLowerCase ? char.ToUpper(c) : c;
        sb.Append("[").Append(c).Append(upperCaseC).Append("]");
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```